# Texto en javascript con '<script></script>'

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy añadiendo un script en html y dentro de un string del estilo. Esto lo hago porque mostramos un trozo de código en nuestra plataforma que queremos que el usuario pueda copiar haciendo click en un botón de copiar:

```
<script>
    function copyCode(){
            $("body").append($temp);
            $temp.val("<div id=\"1"></div>"+
                    "<script>(function(a,b,c) {
                      ...
                     }("a", "b", "c"));
                     </"+"script>").select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            $temp.remove();
    }
</script>
```

El problema es que al cerrar el script de la variable que he creado me da un error (como si asumiera que el cierre del script dentro de la variable es el final del script...).

¿Sabéis alguna manera de solucionarlo?

Actualmente la solución que tengo es esta:

```
var text = '<script> ... </'+'script>';
```

Edit: he añadido el código de manera más completa al igual que he explicado mejor el problema.

Comment: Hola Felix, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y así ganar tu primera medalla). Una posible solución sería romper la cadena para que no aparezca `</script>` (por ejemplo `var text = ‘...</‘+’script>`) pero, aunque eso podría resolver el problema, dejaría un problema de raíz (lo que estás haciendo quizás no sea la mejor manera de hacerlo y el código no es robusto). Edita la pregunta para añadir algo más de detalle (en qué contexto vas a usar `text` luego) y poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Mi comentario se ha quedado parcialmente obsoleto tras la edición. Pero la idea es la misma: ya tienes una solución, para poder mejorarla haría falta saber más sobre qué intentas hacer y cómo.

Comment: ¡Hola! Gracias por la rápida respuesta. Lo que estoy haciendo es un botón que cuando se hace click en éste se copia un HTML el cual tiene una parte de javascript.

Comment: Actualmente lo hago de la siguiente manera:    var $temp = $("<input>");
$("body").append($temp); $temp.val("<el_html_con_el_script_a_copiar">); document.execCommand("copy"); $temp.remove();

Comment: Creo que sería mejor opción crear el elemento script y añadirlo al head: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9413814/761181

Comment: Edita la pregunta para añadir eso (el código no se ve muy bien en los comentarios). ¿Podrías poner el código del script en una función y que se llame al pulsar el botón?

Comment: Hey, ese código me suena. ¿Qué es lo que estás intentando hacer exactamente? ¿Copiar un script al portapapeles?

Comment: Sí, justo estoy haciendo eso Alvaro.

Comment: ¿Dónde se va a pegar el código luego: en la misma página o en otro documento diferente? ¿Y quieres que se copie/pegue como texto o que se ejecute al pegarse?

Comment: El código se pegará en otro documento diferente como texto, para que los que lo copien puedan utilizarlo en un web.

Comment: Si no es un código que vaya a ejecutarse, entonces podrías plantearte cambiar los `<` y `>` por sus entidades `&lt;` y `&gt;`). De lo contrario, el código copiado podría tener efectos secundarios al ser pegado en algunas partes.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro, la creo que por el momento lo dejaré con la solución que he añadido en la edición (pena que sea tan fea...). La verdad es que me resulta raro que haya ese problema al parsear.

Answer (score 4):

Si quieres mostrar código html/js como texto en una página puedes *escapar* los símbolos `<` y `>`, usando `&lt;` (de ***l***ess **t**han, menor que) y `&gt;` (de ***g***reater **t**han, mayor que).

Aquí un simple ejemplo apoyado por la la etiqueta `<pre>`:

```js
$('#texto').html(`<pre>
&lt;script src="/jquery.min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
</pre>`);
```

```css
pre {
background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="texto">
```

Hay una larga lista de caracteres especiales que se pueden mostrar mediante [*HTML Entities*](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)